# In Android, do all the .Java files in the package compile at once?

Tags: android, compilation

I'm kind of a noob at Android, and I downloaded some source code to try to help me learn a bit. When I opened the code, I noticed that many of the .Java files included in the Src folder of the source code had no onCreate() methods. I always assumed that to make a .Java class run, it had to have an onCreate() method.

So... Do all of the .Java files compile and run at once?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .java files need not to be always have onCreate() method. Only the Android Components like Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver containts this onCreate() method as part of their life cycle.

A normal library like .java can have only public class with useful method declaration, so these .java files need not declare onCreate() method or main().

the .java files you are seeing in the project is normal .java file that may contain only constant codes or library class/methods.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful, thorough:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

To explain how other (Android) Java classes work:

Classes without onCreate() will generally have a constructor, like this:

```
public class MyNewClass {
    // We'll leave getters and setters for later.
    int x, y;

    public MyNewClass(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = awesomeMethod(y);
    }

    static public int awesomeMethod(int awesome){
        return awesome*awesome;
    }
}
```

So when in your activity you go:

```
public class SadActivity extends Activity {
    MyNewClass myNewClass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super(b);
        myNewClass = new MyNewClass(2,2);
    }
}
```

At runtime an instance of MyNewClass, helpfully called myNewClass is created using the constructor. And it has a method myNewClass.awesomeMethod() that you can use to square ints. And member variable myNewClass.x (2) and myNewClass.y (4).